# When did people stop translating their names when moving from one country to another?

Tags: everyday-life, immigration, names, given-name

I was interested in the process of people changing their names from one language to another. Most monarchs have a different given name in different languages. However, this phenomenon also applied to ordinary people who either moved from one country to another and had their name changed, or to ordinary people who became famous during their lives and  somehow ended up with their names being translated. This practice seems to have been more common before the 20th century than it is today.

In order to reduce the scope of the question, I am excluding all transliterations from other writing systems. Names from non-Latin writing languages obviously have to be transliterated into the Latin alphabet and the rules for doing so are heavily language-dependant, so those cases are ruled out. I am also excluding monarchs and popes who had Latin-derived names that are translated by tradition.

What I am interested in is the translation of names between two languages using the Latin alphabet and for ordinary people.

Examples of ordinary people changing their names or having them changed:

- *Immanuel Kant's* father changed the spelling of the *Cant* Scottish family he descends from. Even though he never went to France, he is known as *Emmanuel Kant* in France.
- *Henri Nestlé* founder of the namesake company was born in Germany as *Heinrich Nestle*.
- *Jean Ziegler* swiss writer has been born in the German-speaking part of Switzerland as *Hans Ziegler*.
- *Jean-Luc Mélenchon* french politician, descended from a Spanish *Melanchón* family.
- *Nicolas Sarkozy* another french politician, descended from a Hungarian *Sárközy* family. It's not surprising the diacritics were dropped since they don't exist in french language – however, what is more interesting is that he's known in Hungary as *Sarkozy* and not his original Hungarian name, leading to neither the original Hungarian pronunciation, nor to the modern French pronunciation.
- My great-great-grandparents were born in Germany and named *Oskar & Johanna Heftle* but were known in french speaking Switzerland as *Oscar & Jeanne Heftlé*, even though they still both had German citizenship when they married here.

Example of people **not** changing their names:

- A good friend of mine – whose name I'll obviously not spell out here – comes from the German speaking part of Switzerland. His name is a name that has a direct French equivalent and could be easily translated, but I don't think anybody ever had that idea.
- Many immigrants came from former Yugoslavia in the 90s, having names ending in *-ic*.  Those should really be respelled *-itch* (french) or *-itsch* (german) for people to pronounce them correctly. However as far I know such a spelling change was *never* done.

I could go on like that forever, but you get the idea. Nowadays people do not change the spelling of their names when going from a country to another country using the Latin alphabet. This results in major pronunciation errors, confusion, and exclusion of people with those *weird names* even many generations after they fully assimilated to their new country.

My questions is:

- Were those changes in names voluntary in the past, or where they imposed on people moving to a country speaking a foreign language?
- At which point in history did the bureaucracy stop people from altering their names when emigrating from a country to another so that they had to keep the spelling in their original language?

Comment: Related: [The practice of translating foreign monarch's or noble's name](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8486/the-practice-of-translating-foreign-monarchs-or-nobles-name)

Comment: Related but not the same, I'm not talking about nobles specifically :)

Comment: Didn't say they are the same :) Linking it here hoping that it might help you.. Do take a look, some of the answers might be relevant to you

Comment: But Louis XIV or Peter the Great didn't change their names, they used their name in its original form and the translation appeared when people refered to them using other languages. It is a situation quite diferent to the one you describe (someone adopting a new form of their name). Also, you asume it had to do with bureaucracy but it could be just a desire of newcomers to not "stand out", or even misspelling from an era in which you would neither know the correct spelling of your name nor have an official ID with the official spelling on it.

Comment: You mix up two things: translation of names by others and changing name by the person himself. These are two unrelated topics. The first seems to be more like a grammar question.

Comment: OK you guys are definitely right, I mix up different things and have a too broad question. I'll try to improve it, by moving transliteration out.

Comment: One anecdotal point : I know several people who came to Germany from Russia about twenty years ago who had their first names changed. As I understand them, this was not their or their parents choice

Comment: Seems like the advance of the administrative state is the cause here. Everybody has one name which they have to spell one way, otherwise how can their tax, pension, health, education, driving records and so on be accurate?

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that the premise is proven; this is based on anecdotes. We don't know how many people changed their names, how many had their names changed for them, and how many didn't change their names, and how many were changed because they were unpronounceable in the new language.   I don't know the answers to these questions, but I'm skeptical of any answer that doesn't address.

Comment: Or consider romanization that is officially defined by the origin country. The family name "何" used to be spelled "Ho", but since 1958 has been spelled "He". People in English pronounce them differently, but in both cases incorrectly (It should rhyme with "the"). Similarly, "Peking" and "Beijing" should be pronounced identically. The latter *should* be pronounced correctly in English, but because it is "foreign", many people pronounce the "j" like it is French. And Korean has a family name "I" (pronounced "ee"), but to avoid confusing English speakers, the official transliteration was "Lee".

Comment: My grandfathers both at some point after they came to the US around 1910-12 changed their first names from the Polish "Michal" (with a diagonal slash thru the "l") to Michael, and from "Jan" to John. IMO for them it was just a feeling that it would be easier in day-to-day life and assimilation. The too-foreign "dumb Polack" trope was probably widely accepted back then, to the point that my dad even truncated his name when he turned 21 in 1939.

Comment: It hasn't stopped. I live in Thailand, being a Dutch expatriate in retirement. If I chose to become a Thai citizen, I would have to legally change my name into a Thai name.

Comment: I changed my name from Mikhail to Michael when moving to US; therefore the answer to the question is "never."

Comment: I'd like to add that while Nicolas Sarkozy's name is printed in Hungarian the same as in French (there's no transliteration between Latin-script using languages), in the news his name is always pronounced as Hungarian-like "sárközi". not "szarkozi" - they way the announcers would attempt to pronounce a "real" French name. The "szarkozi" variant would also sound somewhat vulgar. Same with ex-Chicago Bears head coach Matt Nagy - he's "nagy", not "nagyi".

Answer (score 12):

You are conflating many different things, some of which still happen regularly:

- Transliteration is still necessary, and it happens a lot, often with differences from one country to the next (cf. Влади́мир Пу́тин/Wladimir Putin/Vladimir Putin/Vladimir Poutine)
- Monarchs' names do get translated, at least occasionally, especially by people who care about royalty. Thus, Elizabeth II is Élisabeth II in French. But there are exceptions (I have never heard anything else than “Juan Carlos” but a comment mentioned the fact that it does get transalted in Hungarian).
- Common people can still change names, but usually that happens when you change citizenship, not merely when you travel, which has become much more common.
- The bureaucracy still forces people to change names all right. I know many people who are stuck with a misspelt or misinterpreted name since they applied for a passport or residence permit.
- You did not mention this but it's not uncommon for people (from China, in particular) to pick a first name like Sarah, Michelle, etc. when they move to Europe or the US and to use it consistently instead of their birth name. Something similar also happens in large multicultural countries like Russia (cf. comment).

But remember that spelling in general (i.e. even for common nouns and other words, not only proper nouns) wasn't always standardized in the way it is today. Another related changed is that many people now know how to write and are expected to fill in forms, etc. Two centuries ago, your name was a spoken word you would tell to a clerk, now it's a written word you have to fill in everywhere. This (much broader) process would seem to readily account for the differences you noted.

Comment: `it's not uncommon for people to pick a first name like Sarah, Michelle, etc. when they move to Europe or the US` Not only when moving outside of coutry. E.g. in Russia many people of national minorities have two names, say, Tatar and Russian (national name is usually an "official" one).

Comment: @user4419802 I didn't know that, will add it to the answer, thanks!

Comment: Misspelling seems to have been common in the past, but maybe as literacy rates rise it's less common. There are claims of Ellis Island immigration officers changing the names of immigrants to the US, but this seems to be largely a myth though misspellings did happen in other ways e.g. on shipping manifests - https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smithsonian-institution/ask-smithsonian-did-ellis-island-officials-really-change-names-immigrants-180961544/

Comment: You are missing a link for [Poutine](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.macleans.ca%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F05%2FMAC06_CANADA_PROJECT_RICHLER_POST01.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.macleans.ca%2Fsociety%2Fwhy-poutine-is-canadas-most-delicious-mess%2F&docid=dMqBssjfjd6xeM&tbnid=PWvooCu52jAlQM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjT2t30q-reAhWGn4MKHWJpDd4QMwhHKAkwCQ..i&w=822&h=462&bih=924&biw=1261&q=poutine&ved=0ahUKEwjT2t30q-reAhWGn4MKHWJpDd4QMwhHKAkwCQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comment: Monarchs' names are seldom translated now, but Popes' names still are. Which suggests it's not a strict or logical process.

Comment: Juan Carlos is definitely János Károly in Hungarian: https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._J%C3%A1nos_K%C3%A1roly_spanyol_kir%C3%A1ly?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @StuartF It depends on language: in hungarian, most well known European monarch is called in the Hungarian equivalent (if there is). There are exceptions, e.g the late Diana is Diana, but Charles is translated to Karoly.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between translation and [transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration). The Чайко́вский example obviously had to be transliterated, and there are different transliteration conventions in different languages.

Interestingly, the cities München, Nürnberg and Köln usually get translated, while Berlin or Hamburg don't. Does the diaeresis have anything to do with it?

Comment: Hamburg (Hambourg, Hamburgo, Amburgo) does too as does Frankfurt, only not in English. Berlin is usually Berlin but that's not universal (cf. Berlijn).

Comment: Köln is an old Roman settlement "Colonia Agrippina". So the question is rather: how Germans could change "Colonia" into "Köln"? (though it fits for Linguistics:SE only)

Comment: München is "modern German". In old time it was Munichen. So it's about evolution of German language too.

Comment: Don't laught, it took me a really long while to figure out that Cologne and Köln were the same city, I actually only figured that out recently.

Comment: @Relaxed - Well, we Americans do love our Hamburgers and Frankfurters...

Comment: @Matt: According to the German Wikipedia, the transition was Colonia -> Coellen (which is a mangled pronounciation of the former, probably by natives who didn't speak Latin) > Cöllen > Cölln > Cöln > Köln. "Coellen" was still used in the 15th century, the other transformations came later.

Comment: @DevSolar, "oe" equals "ö" in German. First the e was written over the o, then the e was simpified into two vertical dashes, then into two dots. So Colonia -> Coellen was the key step.

Comment: @o.m.: Weiß ich. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> At which point in history did the bureaucracy stop people from altering their names when emigrating from a country to another so that they had to keep the spelling in their original language?

The above premise is not true or at least not true for all countries. In the US for example:

- People with mononyms are forced to make up a "last name" even if they don't have one.
- East Asians are forced to reverse their name order to fit the first name first, last name last order.
- If your name has diacritics (especially ones that are unusual in the English language, such as those in Vietnamese), the system will automatically drop them, however important you think they might be.

This can all be occurring within the Latin alphabet. (I have already mentioned Viet Nam, whose script uses the Latin alphabet. Some Indonesians have mononyms and Bahaha Indonesia uses the Latin alphabet. Singapore, which has a variety of populations, uses English and thus the Latin alphabet. People from these countries who emigrate or even simply travel to the US are forced to follow the US naming format.)

I'm not sure about the situation in European countries, but I suspect similar considerations apply.

Comment: My son was born in the UK and as our chosen name contained a non-ASCII character, I was afraid his name would be written incorrectly on the birth certificate and then we'll have to fight bureaucracy to get the correct spelling - but to my utter surprise the clerk at the office in the small British town was able to type the correct ó character. The parents of German tennis player Marc-Kevin Goellner were not this lucky.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not confuse the monarchs with ordinary people. Monarchs usually called by the traditional forms of their names in many countries both then and now.

Regarding spelling of the names of common people, it depends on the language rules, I an totally sure I would change the spelling of my name when moving from Russia to another country.

Comment: Obviously, because it's not the same alphabet :) So this is transliteration and not really translation (although it's possible to do both). But if you'd move to another non-russian speaking cyrillic writing country, such as Bulgaria, Serbia or Mongolia, would you have to change anything ?

Comment: @Bregalad "But if you'd move to another non-russian speaking cyrillic writing country, such as Bulgaria, Serbia or Mongolia, would you have to change anything?" - yes, if their reading rules are different so that my name is read differently if spelled as it is. For instance, in Ukraine I would have to change ы->и and и->i